# Oracle APEX - LOV on a column to show distinct values except one

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

On Interactive Grid - I have a column "TaskID" and other column is "Predecessors".
I want Predecessors column to be LOV with the distinct values on TASKID except the current row TASKID. Any suggestions on how this can be done? Thanks.

I'm using below SQL for the predecessors LOV, however this shows the entire list including the current column TASKID.

```
"select DISTINCT(TRANSITION_TASKS_NEW.TASKID) from TRANSITION_TASKS_NEW"
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like this?

```
with task as(
select 'a' as task_id from dual
union all
select 'b' from dual
union all 
select 'c' from dual
union all
select 'd' from dual)
select x.task_id from task x
where task_id in (
    select task_id 
    from task y 
    where y.task_id != :vTaskID);
```

Comment: Can you please explain me how this code works? What is the outcome of this

Comment: Will this code work?    "select DISTINCT(TRANSITION_TASKS_NEW.TASKID) from TRANSITION_TASKS_NEW" WHERE TRANSITION_TASKS_NEW.TASKID != :TASKID

Comment: yes, even better. mine has an unnecessary 2nd table.